# Real copy to Android device

Tags: filesystems, files, cache, android

When i copy files to the Android phone, they are copied to some cache, but they aren't written. I don't like it, because i don't know what is done.

I've tried these methods:

- copying via `thunar` file manager
- using `cp src dst` command
- using `rsync -aP src dst`

I have to use `sync` to write data. I don't like it, because i can't see progress when copying large amount of data (using thunar, rsync).

Comment: Are you open to using a Web interface?

Comment: @Tim Yes, i'm open, but it also depends on how huge is that web interface.

Comment: How is your Android device's filesystem mounted in your case?

Comment: Mounting it with a `sync` option could make all the operation much less efficient.

Comment: @imz Not mounting. I've mounted it without any options and then copied large files in few secs. Then I've executed command `sync` and waited for filesystem synchronization this took over 10 minutes.

Comment: Mount options -- that's one way to affect this caching behaviour.